# Deploying Office 2013 Home and Business via System Center Configuration Manager 2012 R2

Tags: licensing, deployment, system-center, microsoft-office-2013, configuration-management

It's beginning to seem like I am chasing my tail on this one so I am going to ask the question here to see if anyone else has an answer to this.

I have been trying to get SCCM 2012 setup and my current issue is deploying Microsoft Office 2013 Home and Business to clients.

From what I have read at [Deployment methods for Office 2013](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee624360(v=office.15).aspx#Table) there is two ways to deploy Office.  You can either customize an MSI install using the Office Customization Tool ([How-to: Deploying Microsoft Office 2013 using SCCM 2012](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/How-to-Deploying-Office-0f954e7f)) or you customize a Click-to-Run deployment ([Deploying and Updating Office 2013 or Office 365 Click-to-Run with App-V 5.0 and Configuration Manager 2012](http://blogs.technet.com/b/pauljones/archive/2013/08/28/office-2013-click-to-run-with-configuration-manager-2012.aspx))

This is all good documentation but it all revolves and refers to **Office 2013 Professional Plus**.  I cannot find any documentation that refers to **Home and Business**.  The table in the "Deployment methods" document from Microsoft seems to indicate that Home and Business Retail can and should be deployed via Click-to-Run but here is where I run into a dilemma:

1. Can I use a Office 2013 Professional Plus MSI with a Home and Business product key and be within the licensing agreement as long as the installer only installs the components that are licensed under the Home and Business version?  If so then please provide link to Microsoft Document that I can show the auditor when he comes calling.
2. For a Click-to-Run deployment what would be the Product ID for Home and Business that I would use in the  element of the XML Configuration file?

Answer (score 2):

> Can I use a Office 2013 Professional Plus MSI with a Home and Business product key and be within the licensing agreement

No.

> For a Click-to-Run deployment what would be the Product ID for Home and Business that I would use in the element of the XML Configuration file?

See below.

```
 <Product ID="HomeBusinessRetail">
```

And what seems to be [a helpful blog post on the matter of deploying Office 2013 Home and Business in a Click-to-Run scenario, here](http://thommck.wordpress.com/2014/05/07/the-mdt-and-office-2013-click-to-run-jigsaw-puzzle/).

Comment: That's exactly what I've been looking for.  I'll try that first thing in the morning.  Thanks

Comment: I think this is working.  Something is getting downloaded, but the Office Deployment Tool is not showing me any kind of status messages as it is doing it.  Is there a trick?  Also, when I try to do the package step it is returning really fast without the expected app-v package or any status messages to say if it passed or failed and why.

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy any component of the Office 2013 suite as Click-to-Run via specifying the **Product ID**s here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2842297/.  Meeting the license requirement is another story.  You can still do key-based activation/licensing by specifying `AUTOACTIVATE = 0` in the `Property` element of your XML file.

Further configuration.xml reference from technet: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219426(v=office.15).aspx